# Can't add UIButton to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview, uibutton

Goodevening

Although i've read quite a lot related questions about adding a UIButton to a UIScrollView it doesn't work for me. When i use UIImages instead of UIButtons it works like a charm. What am i missing here? (don't mind the if's or for-loops, al those are correct, paths of images also)

```
 for(int j = 0; j < [subcategorie count]; j++){

        NSArray *product = [subcategorie objectAtIndex:(j)];
        int posX = 0;
        for(int k = 1; k <= [product count]; k++){

            if((i-1) == currentCategory ){
                //NSString *fotoName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"images/product/%@/%@_%i.png",self.categorieen[(i-1)] ,self.categorieen[(i-1)] , k];

                NSString *fotoName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%i",self.categorieen[(i-1)] , k];

                NSString *currentCategory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"images/product/%@/", self.categorieen[(i-1)]];
                NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fotoName ofType:@"png" inDirectory:currentCategory];

                UIButton *fotoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                [fotoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:path] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                fotoButton.frame = CGRectMake(posX, 252, 718, 520);
                fotoButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                self.scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(posX, 252);
                [self.scrollview setBounces:YES];
                [self.scrollview setPagingEnabled:YES];
                [self.scrollview addSubview:fotoButton];
                [self.scrollview bringSubviewToFront:fotoButton];
                [self.scrollview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

                self.scrollview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                [self addSubview: self.scrollview];
                posX += 718;

                NSLog(@"Fotolink = %@", fotoName);
            }

        }
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: in [fotoButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:path] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; UIImage imageNamed part is incorrect,try adding this [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[UIImage imageNamed:path]` looks incorrect,
try  `[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]`

---

```
UIButton *fotoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[fotoButton setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: That was indeed the fault. Thilina Hewagama just said the same. Thanks anyway!